# Find all substrings of a string

Tags: c, string, printf

I have a string where I need to do substring operation.  I'm trying to achieve something like this for example if the input string is `com` then the output must be something like this -

`c` 
`co` 
`com` 
`o`
 `om`
 `m`.. I have tried this

```
for(int i=0 ; i<len ;i++)
{
    printf("%s",&string[strlen(string)-i]));
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It's not clear... You want the values stored somewhere or what? What will you do with the substrings?

Comment: You need two nested loops: One for the start and one for the substring length. And you need a way to print (or hatever you want to do) a substring based on start and length.

Comment: I dont want the stored values . i just want to split up the input string as shown in the question.

Comment: made the edit. sorry for the typo @iharob

Comment: Split it and output it immediately?

Comment: Are you trying to find the correct usage for `printf` or are you trying to figure out what substring pattern will generate your provided output?  Because the latter smells a lot like homework.

Comment: I get the point but not able to implement it @MOehm

Comment: Do you consider `""` a sub-string of `"com"`?

Comment: just two loops: `void substrings(const char *word) { for (; *word; word++) { for (int len = 1; len <= strlen(word); len++) printf("%.*s", len, word); }}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A substring is defined by its left and right ends so there are `O(n*n)` substrings in a string of length `n`.

```
int n = strlen(string);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{   for(int j = i; j < n; j++)
    {   /* print substring from i to j */
        for(int k = i; k <= j; k++)
        {   printf("%c", string[k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma in your code:

```
for(int i=0 ; i<len ;i++)
{
    printf("%s", &string[strlen(string)-i])
}
```

But that will print "", "m", "om" - not what you want.

Something more like:

```
// start at each point in the string
for ( const char *start = string; *start; ++start )
{
  // for each starting point, go from the whole remainder down
  // to just one character
  for ( const char *end = string + strlen(string); end > start; --end )
  {
    for ( const char *s = start; s < end; ++s )
      putchar(*s);

    putchar('\n');   
  }
}
```

Example: https://ideone.com/XXoYv6

Answer (score 0):

- Substring means any contiguous group of characters.
- For the n string
  it will generate (n*(n-1) /2) substrings.
- For example of String
  source = "STACK"
  Length of the character is 5, so it total substring would be (5(5-1) /2) = 10

We have to iterate through the first element of string and print all the substring and than onwards one by one we increment the index of i and printing the substring from range (j to k)

```
public void generateSubString(String source){
        char[] arr = source.toCharArray();
        for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
            for(int j = i ; j < arr.length; j++){
                for(int k = i; k<=j; k++){
                    System.out.print(arr[k]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
```

OUTPUT:

S
ST
STA
STAC
STACK
T
TA
TAC
TACK
A
AC
ACK
C
CK
K

Answer (score -1):

Below is the code to find all substrings of a string in javascript without for loop, which will increase the speed of code.

```
const devideSubStr = (str) => {
 var totalLoop = str.length * ((str.length + 1)/2);
 // looping count
 let i = 0;
 var totalChar = 1;//character to get
 var charFrom = 0;// from which index
 var strLength = str.length;//length of digit
 while( i < totalLoop){     
      console.log(str.substr(charFrom, totalChar))
      charFrom ++;
      i ++;
      if(charFrom == strLength){
          charFrom = 0;
          strLength = strLength - 1;
          totalChar ++;
      }  
 }}
```